# unknown directive "@isAuthenticated". Using Neo4j and Graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({
  typeDefs,
  driver,
  resolvers,
  config: {
    jwt: {
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'secret',
    },
    database: process.env.NEO4J_DATABASE || 'neo4j',
    auth: {
      isAuthenticated: true,
      hasRole: true,
    },

  },
})
```

but when I do that in my graphql.schema :

```
type Avatar @isAuthenticated {
      avatarId: ID! @id
      name: String! @unique
      picture: String!
      coinPrice: Int!
      collections: [AvatarCollection]
        @relationship(type: "AVATAR_COLLECTION_AVATAR", direction: IN)
    }
```

I get this error :

```
unknown directive "@isAuthenticated".
```

how am I supposed to add the directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do that with Neo4jGraphql was :

```
type Avatar @auth(rules: [{ operations: [CREATE], isAuthenticated: true }]) 
    {
       avatarId: ID!
        ...
    }
```

see this doc for more informations :
https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/auth/